# I want to use urdu in webpage using codeigniter framework?

Tags: php, codeigniter, html, urdu

I am developing a website using urdu in codeigniter framework. I want to load
urdu in my webpages but I failed every time.
I send urdu to database in uni code when I am trying to access urdu data and show it in webpage it show me some other things which is in attachment.
[image: This is screenshot of webpage]

I already used meta tag below

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

How can I write urdu in webpage using codeigniter framework.

Comment: can you tell me which editor you using for development?

Comment: Sublime Text and for testing chrome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step : 1 - Go to table structure and change collation **latin1_swedish_ci** to **utf8_general_ci**

Step : 2 - You have to include this following tag in data results pages.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Step :3 - Insert 'N' Prefix. Here the N stands for National language character set. Which means that you are passing an NCHAR, NVARCHAR or NTEXT value

Step :4 - PHP code displaying records form database. Before that you have to specify mysql_query() function data character set type

```
<?php
include('db.php');
mysql_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'"); 
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM books") or die(mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
echo $row['id']; // Book id 
echo $row['books_title']; // Book title
}
?>
```

Comment: How can i use set character_set_results='utf8' in codeiginator

Comment: @Ayazkhan if it helped you please upvote the answer to help others.

Comment: Codeigniter has it on database set up if you autoload database you do not need to include it like you have done https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer i found after a lot of research that you have to set your database table collation to **utf8_general_ci** and it will help you a lot.

Below line is must in your page header

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I Just solve the problem by adding the following header in each __constructor. you may add this in parent controller

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```