# How Retrieve urdu Data from database in urdu format?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, performance

Hi i'm developing a web based question paper generator using Codeigniter in which i have to store questions in Urdu and English Language its working well for English's Questions But at time of retrieving Urdu's question its format does not meets actual format of Urdu I'm getting following result:

Current output

[image]

While my desired input is as this format:
[image]

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
  <fieldset>
   <legend>All Questions</legend>
   <div id="questions" lang="ur" style="text-align: right;">
    <?php 
     if(isset($posted['subject_id'])){
      $id = $posted['chapter_id'];
      $query=$this->db->select()
                      ->from('short_question')
                      ->where('chapter_id', $id)
                      ->get();
                       $result= $query->result();
                        if($result){
       $counter = 1;
                       foreach ($result as $row) { ?>
              <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-12">
              <?= $row->s_question ?> <?= $counter ?>                       
         </div>
       </div>
        
       <?php 
       $counter++;
       }
      }else {
       echo '<center><h2>No Record Found</h2></center>';
      }
     }
    ?>
   
  </fieldset>
  </div>
```

here is my code i'm new to stackover flow please ignore I've made any mistake while posting question....... 
Thanks in advance

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/41146175/3602846

Comment: I saw that but that is about how to store urdu in database my problem is that how to display urdu data in urdu format...

Answer (score 0):

Go to table structure and change collation **latin1_swedish_ci** to **utf8_general_ci**.
You will get the normal array as response and display it as you are using for English.